# how to make an iframe that is always visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

Is it possible to have an iframe that is always visible on an html page?
By always visible i mean always on top, no other element can be over it and this needs to be done from inside the iframe.

My first try was setting z-index of the iframe with the highest possible value (it also needs a relative position to work), however this can't be done from inside the iframe because of the same origin policy.

Is this even possible?

**EDIT :**

If it's not is it possible to detect if there is something overlapping a part of it's content?

Comment: Without having access to the document containing the iframe, no, you won't be able to tell if elements have been layered on top of the iframe, or even (I believe) if the iframe is even visible. The only positioning-related thing I can think of you really know is the height and width at which the iframe is being displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, what you're trying to do isn't possible.

The document containing the iframe controls its layout and position on the page, including its z-index, size, display, position, etc. All of the iframe's contents are treated as one layer within the containing document, so positioning within the iframe will have no effect on how its elements interact with the outer document.

To make the iframe be displayed in front of all other elements via code within the iframe, you would have to be able to manipulate the containing document, which, as you say, you are unable to because of the same-origin policy.